# Suspension of the $(-1)$-sphere

Tags: general-topology

I have a doubt about the construction of the suspension of the sphere of dimension -1, that is the empty set. In the following image I try to explain the suspension of the empty set:

[image]

My doubt is that I think that the "part" of the empty set that result of the product of one of the endpoints of the line with the empty space is collapsed with a point and we proceed in this way with the other remaining point, but the empty space no have points, then,  where the points come from?  Am I correct with the thinking of collapse the empty space with a point "two times"?

Comment: I have no sensible way of answering your question so I will just say that perhaps sometimes definitions shouldn't be extended to pathological cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Reduced) suspension is equivalent to taking $S^{0} * X$, where $*$ is the (reduced) join and $S^{0}$ is the $0$-sphere. If $X$ is empty, then $\Sigma X \simeq S^{0}$, which is precisely the two-pointed space that you compute.

Comment: thank you very much user02138!

Comment: doesn't X need a basepoint for one to take the reduced suspension?

Comment: Sure, if $X$ is not empty.

Answer (score 1):

The whole question is maybe somewhat up to convention. But the usual convention makes sense here.
If we look at the definition of the quotient for spaces $A\subset X$ carfully, then we see that $X/A$ consist of one point $[A]$ and all the points of $X-A$. If we now consider $X/\emptyset$, then this is all the points of $X$ and one point $[\emptyset]$.
Hence if you take the unreduced suspension you end up with two points.

Comment: And that is good as the discrete 2 point space is the $0$-sphere, being the boundary of the 1-ball, which is a closed interval!